# Serialization of Singleton Classes during RMI communcation

Tags: java, singleton, deserialization, rmi, distributed-objects

While I was going through the explanation of readResolve method , lot of references explain that this method will be useful to gurantee the singleton property when singleton class is deserialzied while object of that class is serialized and transferred over RMI .

Now my question is when RMI call takes place , Singleton class Object will be transported over different JVM (having different classloader) , so after deserialization we will have another instance of singleton class (in different JVM) . Am I right ?

So in the context of RMI calls , what is use of implementing readResolve method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So that if you send it *again,* it resolves to the one that is already there. Which would probably be contrary to your intention. Don't confuse yourself by using singletons in RMI.

Comment: So you mean to say , readResolve ensures that singleton property is maintained with in a single JVM ?   
if readResolve method is not in that class, every time we do deserialization on RMI client , it will create different instance. Am I correct ?

Comment: That's what I said. I'm not fond of this 'so you mean to say' game.